# jQuery - functions moving to window.function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a new global object and then put everything in to that new object so it doesn't interfere with anything else anyone else does.  After calling the document.ready() function this gets moved to window.bf for unknown reasons.  I've reduced this down to a simple example.  Anyone have any ideas on what is happening?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    debugger;
    var bf = {}; // Namespace

    bf.vars = [];
    bf.vars['onclick'] = "";

    $(document).ready(function() {

      bf.noop = function() {}

      bf.noop();
      window.bf.noop();

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>Test</body>

</html>
```

So I wind up with two "bf"s.  One is the original global object and the second one is the window.bf object.  My problem is: Originally, the global object had all of the functions and variables in it.  Now the global variable has nothing except bf.vars (an array).  Everything else is now in the window.bf object (including everything that was supposed to go in to the global bf.vars array yet I never asked for that to happen.

Up until last Friday (9/25/2015) this did not happen.  Now it does.

Update: I just tried removing the document.ready() function.  If you remove the document.ready() part - then the global bf object goes back to being a global variable.  So this appears to have something to do with jQuery itself.

Before anyone asks: The reason the document.ready() is being used is because some of the functions I define make reference to locations that need to be loaded and jQuery says to use the document.ready() function in order to ensure all elements have been loaded before execution starts.  The bf.noop() function is just to give an example of a function and to show that the function no longer shows up in the global bf object.

Screen capture with document.ready():

[image]

Screen capture without document.ready():

[image]

Better?

Comment: In a browser, the global context is the `window` object. Every variable you declare with `var` in the global context (that is, outside of any function) will become a property of the `window` object.

Comment: ... and the `$(document).ready()` thing here has no effect on anything, other than delaying for a little while the creation of the "noop" property on the object referenced by `bf`.

Comment: If I run the debugger in FireFox.  There are two variables.  The global bf object (it shows up as just +bf).  A second entry shows up after the document.ready() is through (ie: window->+bf).  If the document.ready() is left off only the first one (ie: +bf) shows up.  WITH: the +bf only as vars and window->bf has vars and functions.  WITHOUT: the +bf has both vars and functions.

Comment: No, that's really not how it works. When you create the global `bf`, that immediately creates `window.bf` because that's what global variables are.

Comment: Try this: `var foo = "hello"; alert(window.foo);`

Comment: I just added two screen captures.  Does this make it clearer?

Comment: have you tried manipulating one of them to see if there is a real difference between your "two" variables?

Comment: Yes.  I get a "No such function as bf.noop()" in the first.  The second works without an error.

Comment: I tried to edit my reply - but too late.  The reason for the "no such..." message is because bf.noop() has not yet been instantiated because of the document.ready() function.  I believe rossipedia has the right answer.  It is a problem of scope.  Some of my function calls are outside of the document.ready() and thus are executed first, before everything is ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the top-level scope of a script tag, all variables get implicitly attached to `window`.

The good news is, you actually *don't* have two `bf` objects, you only have one with two ways to access it.

```js
var bf = {};
bf.foo = "bar";
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(window.bf, undefined, 4);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Please see the screen captures and note the differences.  Thanks!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then everything is still working as it should be. Without the `document.ready` call, the `noop` function gets attached to the `bf` object immediately, whereas _with_ the call it gets attached inside of a function, which is a completely different scope than where the `debugger` statement is.

Comment: That would be interesting.  I did have an error but I tracked that down to the call to the function being outside of the document.ready() so the function had as of yet to be instantiated.  I think you have the solution to my problem.  So the only question left is why doesn't FireFox update properly after everything has loaded and run?  Er...I mean Firebug?

Comment: I can't repro using jQuery 2.1.3 and the code you posted. There must be something else happening that is overwriting your `bf` variable.

Comment: I am not sure but I think it might have something to do with the menu I'm creating.  It has over 3,000 entries.  However, as I stated, up until last Friday everything worked just how it was.  I was adding in a new function when everything just went bonkers.  I have even removed that function to no avail.  Makes me wonder if I've clobbered memory somewhere.

Comment: I just re-read your last post.  So jqv2.1.3 is ok but jqv1.11.1|3 is not.  Sounds like a bug in jq that was fixed in v2.  I'm going to try moving some things around and see if the error moves with it. If it does - then it has to be in MY code.  If it doesn't then it is probably something in jqv1.11.1|3.

Answer (score 4):

A variable declared outside the scope of a function is bound to the global scope. Since you're declaring `var bf = {}` inside the script tag, its parent is the `window` object.

[This MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is a good read on variables in JavaScript.

Comment: Please see the screen captures and note the differences.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rossipedia has both two good answers as well as leading me to find the problem.  See his posts.

For unknown reasons, jQuery version 1.11.1 (I'm using v1.11.3 and thus the 1.11.1|3 in my post) has some kind of an error that was fixed in jQuery version 2.1.3.

But I also found that one of the programs I use to generate the menu for our site was generating an old function name (showIt instead of show_menu) which was causing problems also.  By fixing the generated function name the problem has gone away.

This does NOT mean that the jQuery folks can go "Yeah!  We don't have to fix anything!" because this is a valid error and the simple code I posted shows how to break jQuery which might mean there is some way to cause real problems with jQuery.  So basically, this should be looked at by someone more in tune with jQuery to find out why the code I posted does what it does.  Then they can come back and say "You idiot! You did BLAH! and you shouldn't have!" or maybe "Thanks for locating this really obscure problem that no one else in the entire world has come across or cares about."  In any event - this is now a known problem. :-)

Comment: With all respect, I don't think there's a jQuery bug; at least, if there is, I haven't seen any direct evidence that there's a bug. Can you create a jsfiddle or a CodePen or something to demonstrate it? (If you expect any jQuery contributor to fix it, you'll kind-of need to do that anyway when you log a bug.)

Comment: If you look at the original code and then at the screen captures - you see what is going on.  Rossipedia tested this under jq v2.1.3 and reported that it gave different results. This difference would be the "bug".  You may not feel this counts as a "bug" - but shouldn't jq give the same results?  Also, this was tested on all of the major browsers by myself with the same results.  So I do not believe it to be a browser or Javascript problem.

Comment: No, it's not clear at all what you're even talking about. What **exactly** is the code that works differently with the two versions of jQuery? Of course you don't need to tell me here; like I said, if you think this should be fixed, then the only way that'll happen is if you log a bug at the jQuery bug tracker. However, if you did post a clear description of what's going wrong, and a jsfiddle or something to demonstrate the issue, then I would be happy to log a bug and even investigate. (I'm not a jQuery contributor, but I know some.)

Comment: Did you not read my response?  You would have to talk to Rossipedia to find out the differences as he was the one to test it under the two different versions of jQuery.  All I know is: With the document.ready, bf does not have the noop() function and without it - bf does have the noop function.  Can you explain why that is happening?  Rossipedia did by saying under v2.1.3 it shows up in both instances.  Therefore, if it is not showing in both in v1.11.1|3.  Then there's a problem.

Comment: Well, I read his answer differently. He says he cannot reproduce the problem with 2.1.3, but I don't see where he clearly says that he *can* reproduce the problem with the older version of the library. It would be extremely weird for jQuery to cause a problem like this anyway (especially since there really is no underlying problem).

Comment: That is correct.  But I do not think you are looking at his answer in the right way.  If he can not reproduce what I got (and he got) under v1.11.1|3, then that means it is working differently under v2.1.3.  What changed to make it act differently? The v2 versions of jQuery were re-written to work with later browsers.  Could something in that re-write have changed so this no longer shows up?  In any event - this is becoming a discussion rather than answering a question.  As I said, I figured out how to get around this problem based on what Rossipedia posted.  I'm happy. :-)

Comment: I just went back and re-read everything.  Note that Rossipedia also said it might be a problem with how Firebug updates its information and not a bug with jQuery.  Just thought I'd remind you of that.  However, both screen shots were taken after the code had executed.  So I'm discounting it being a Firebug problem.  But he may have a very valid point too.  :-?

Comment: Yes, the debugger can be tricky.  The simple fact is that a `var` declaration in the global context is exactly, precisely the same thing as creating a new property of `window`.